# TypeError: fun is not a function

Tags: javascript

when i have call `OpenModelWindow` function show me error `fun is not a function` here is my function code

```
function OpenModelWindow(url, option) {

        var fun;
        try {
            if (parent != null && parent.$ != null && parent.$.ShowIfrmDailog != undefined) {
                fun = parent.$.ShowIfrmDailog
            }
            else {
                fun = $.ShowIfrmDailog;
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            fun = $.ShowIfrmDailog;
        }
        fun(url, option);
    }
```

Comment: Really, fun is not a function

Comment: can you check the value of `typeof fun`

Comment: I'm not best in javascript but realy `fun is not a function` you just declare this variable at the top, and call it at the botom like function.

Comment: @Baterson - OP's code doesn't "just" declare it at the top and call it at the bottom: the part in between assigns a value that is expected to be a function reference. (Obviously that isn't working for some reason, but it's fine conceptually.)

Comment: P.S. Is "ShowIfrmDailog" a typo, with the "a" and "i" in "Dialog" the wrong way around?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, but `fun(url, option)` called in one scope with `var fun`, like I saw.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `fun` if probably undefined. To solve that, check for type of `fun`:

```
function OpenModelWindow(url, option) {

    var fun;
    try {
        if (parent != null && parent.$ != null && parent.$.ShowIfrmDailog != undefined) {
            fun = parent.$.ShowIfrmDailog
        }
        else {
            fun = $.ShowIfrmDailog;
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        fun = $.ShowIfrmDailog;
    }
    if (typeof fun == 'function') // <----
        fun(url, option);
}
```